# Deleting file in Python not working

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to delete a temp file using:

```
os.remove(str('temp.bin'))
```

Here is the complete function, note that I am using an API (XWF) to read out data into a file, which works fine as is. This works fine when it receives a valid image, so the problem isn't outside of this close. The code only has issues when it receives a non-valid image file. I read the input into temp files because it works well for my solution, the issue here being that it won't delete them when they are not valid images. I'm not looking for a lecture on why it would be better to detect whether or not it's an image before writing it to a temp file. Humor me and presume for now that I have a good reason for doing so.

```
import OutputRedirector
import XWF
import os
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS, GPSTAGS

gps_data = {}

def XT_ProcessItemEx(nItem, hItem, reserved):
    global gps_data
    fn = XWF.GetItemName(nItem)
    offset = 0
    size = XWF.GetItemSize(nItem)
    if offset < size:
        tempfn = fn + '.bin'
        f = open(tempfn, 'wb')
        buffer = XWF.Read(hItem, offset, size)
        f.write(buffer)
        f.close()
        try:
            image = Image.open(tempfn)
            exif_data = get_exif_data(image)
            gps = get_lat_lon(exif_data)
            if gps[0]:
                gps_data[fn] = (repr(gps[0]), repr(gps[1]))
                print('Found GPS data in %s' % fn)
            else:
                print('No GPS data in image %s' % fn)
            del image
            os.remove(str(tempfn)) # it works fine here
        except IOError:
            print('Not an image')
            os.remove(str(f)) # but it won't work here
    else:
        print('File too small')
    return
```

If I don't leave that line as is and don't use the str() enclosure I get this error:

```
TypeError :  must be string, not file
```

As is I get this error:

```
WindowsError :  [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume 
label syntax is incorrect: "<closed file u'file.pdf.bin', 
mode 'wb' at 0x0A82A0D0>"
```

If I move the offending line directly before return at the function/method root level I get this error:

```
WindowsError :  [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because 
it is being used by another process
```

I'm not sure why it works with image but not with f.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to use the *file* object, not the filename. Either use `os.remove(f.name)` or use `os.remove(tmpfn)`.

You also want to switch to using files as context managers (with the `with` statement) so that they are closed automatically, and perhaps the [`tempfile` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) is of interest to you as well.

Using `with`:

```
with open(tempfn, 'wb') as f:
    buffer = XWF.Read(hItem, offset, size)
    f.write(buffer)
```

(note the omission of `f.close()` here.

Using `tempfile`; the `TemporaryFile` is *automatically* cleaned up on close:

```
from tempfile import TemporaryFile


with TemporaryFile(prefix=fn) as tmpfile:
    tmpfile.write(XWF.Read(hItem, offset, size))
    tmpfile.seek(0)
    try:
        image = Image.open(tmpfile)
        exif_data = get_exif_data(image)
    except IOError:
        print 'Not an image'
        return

    gps = get_lat_lon(exif_data)
    if gps[0]:
        gps_data[fn] = (repr(gps[0]), repr(gps[1]))
        print('Found GPS data in %s' % fn)
    else:
        print('No GPS data in image %s' % fn)

    del image

 # tmpfile is automatically closed because we used it as a context manager
```

You also want to minimize what you put in a `try` block, only catch the `IOError` when actually reading image data, not before.

Comment: Then I get the error I mentioned at the end: `WindowsError :  [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: u'temp.pdf.bin' `

Comment: but it still doesn't let me delete the file, it says the process can't access the file

Comment: @DanO'Day: What are you trying to delete still here? `os.remove(tempfn)` or something else?

Comment: Disregard, using temp file is a much better solution. Thanks!

Comment: Slightly updated, I realized `tempfile` objects are contextmanagers too.

Comment: Excellent, even better. Thanks again

Comment: I got the same error even I'm using with. but my problem solved after use open and close manually

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, one of the problems is due to a misfeature of PIL.

If you do an `Image.open(filename)` on a non-image file, it raises an `IOError`, but it doesn't close the open file, which is a bit naughty...

```
>>> import os
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> i = Image.open('something.bin')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Progra~1\Python\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1980, in open
    raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
IOError: cannot identify image file
>>> os.remove('something.bin')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'something.bin'
```

You can work around it by giving it a file object instead...

```
filename = 'something.bin'
f = open(filename, 'rb')
try:
    i = Image.open(f)
    # do the thing
except IOError:
   f.close()
   os.remove(filename)
```

However, if you've already loaded all the image data into RAM, there doesn't seem to be much point in creating a temp file. You could just use a `StringIO`...

```
from cStringIO import StringIO

def XT_ProcessItemEx(nItem, hItem, reserved):
    global gps_data
    fn = XWF.GetItemName(nItem)
    offset = 0
    size = XWF.GetItemSize(nItem)
    if offset < size:
        buffer = XWF.Read(hItem, offset, size)
        sio = StringIO(buffer)
        try:
            image = Image.open(sio)
            exif_data = get_exif_data(image)
            gps = get_lat_lon(exif_data)
            if gps[0]:
                gps_data[fn] = (repr(gps[0]), repr(gps[1]))
                print('Found GPS data in %s' % fn)
            else:
                print('No GPS data in image %s' % fn)
        except IOError:
            print('Not an image')
    else:
        print('File too small')
    return
```

Comment: Thanks! Oddly enough, I started this project using StringIO but switched to temp files because of the PIL error. At the time though, I assumed it was an issue with my code, not PIL, so I stopped using StringIO haha